# How many edges to be removed to always guarantee disconnected graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Assumed undirected graph G is connected. G has $6$-vertices and $10$ edges.

What will be the minimum number of edges whose deletion from graph G is always guaranteed that it will become disconnected ?

---

I randomly tried for many graphs and can say that removing $3$ edges from most of them produces disconnected graph.

But, I don't have any proof or generalization to confirm this ? Is this correct ?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean. One interpretation of the problem is that you're asking for the minimum $k$ such that no matter what $G$ is, removing *any* set of $k$ edges disconnects it. This is what Taisuke Yasuda's answer is about.

Comment: The other interpretation is that you're asking for the minimum $k$ such that no matter what $G$ is, you can *choose* a set of $k$ edges that disconnects it. This is what Bob Krueger's answer is about

Comment: @EspeciallyLime I think your first interpretation is what actually meant .

Comment: @EspeciallyLime thanks for the clarification. In retrospect, I think I went with my interpretation because that interpretation yields the answer the OP thought it was (i.e., 3).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: think about maximally acyclic connected graphs (trees).

Answer (score 12):

Hint: what is the average degree of your graph? There must be a vertex of at or below average degree. Try to disconnect this vertex from the graph.

Comment: Thanks !! I got cleared with 2 questions here . Removing a particular set of edges (i.e 3) and removing any set of edges (i.e 6)

Answer (score 3):

With 6 nodes the spanning tree will consist of 5 edges. Since you have 10 edges, if you remove 6 edges you won't have enough edges to make a spanning tree and thus the result must be disconnected. Remove any fewer then 6 edges and you might still have a spanning tree and remained connected.

So your answer is 6.

In general, with N vertices and M edges where M is >= N the answer is M-(N-1).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. There will always be a vertex with 3 or fewer edges and removing those will produce a disconnected graph.